# Git zsh autocomplete only filenames

Tags: git

Ok, I have zsh Git auto complete already working. What I'm trying to do is be able to autocomplete only the file names of any files listed in the `git status`.

For example I run `git status` and the following files are visible:

```
/a/b/c/d/foo.java
/e/f/g/h/bar.java
```

What I'd like to be able to do is run `git diff` and then be able to tab complete either `foo.java` or `bar.java`.

Comment: will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107546/how-to-git-diff-without-typing-the-whole-path

Comment: I actually just saw that, and I have done that. Only thing is, the filename still has to be fully typed out. I'm hoping to devise a way to tab complete that. Close though.